# LINQ consumes a lot of CPU resources

Tags: c#, performance, linq, asp.net-core

The code below takes up as much as 22% of the CPU.

```
public async Task<Client> SingleByIdAsync(string clientId)
{
    var baseQuery = _configurationDbContext.Clients.Where(p => p.ClientId == clientId).Include(p => p.ClientSecrets);

    await baseQuery.SelectMany(p => p.Scopes).Include(p => p.ApiScope).LoadAsync();

    return await baseQuery.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

`LoadAsync` consumes 8% of CPU.
And another function consumes 17% of CPU:

```
public async Task<List<ApiResource>> FindByScopesNameAsync(List<string> scopes)
        {
            return await _configurationDbContext.ApiResources.Where(p => p.Scopes.Any(x => scopes.Any(y => y == x.ApiScope.Name))).Select(p => p).ToListAsync();
        }
```

My question is what is wrong with this linq? Why is it taking so many resources? How can I optimize them?

Comment: do you have a benchmark of non-linq way? and this is more of **EF**, not only linq.

Comment: it depends on row's count returned by query.

Comment: Why you call `LoadAsync` when you need just one record?

Comment: What database are you connecting to, and where is it located? Is it located on the same machine?

Comment: I connect to MSSQL. It's on the same machine because I'm doing everything on the localhost. I call `LoadAsync` because without it my ApiScope in ClientScope in `List<ClientScope> Scopes` is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found a surprisingly good solution. I did this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ConfigurationDbContext>(cfg =>
{
    cfg.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"), x =>
    {
        x.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
    });
});
```

so I just set up QuerySplittingBehavior to SplitQuery. This solution is so efficient that I can now handle up to 1000 out of 100 supported requests per second (according to Loading Tests performed on 8 threads).

Answer (score 4):

The CPU is not consumed by the LINQ-query itself, but by Entity Framework which is loading your results into memory.

The LINQ-Queries get translated into SQL. The performance overhead here is negligible.

But when you call `LoadAsync()`, all `ClientSecrets`, `Scopes` and `ApiScopes` which are related to the `Client` are loaded into memory. Loading a lot of data into one `DbContext` and its `ChangeTracker` causes significant CPU load.

So instead of loading everything into memory, try to load the `Client` and then only load the `ApiScopes` which are directly related to that client.

In addition, you can turn `ChangeTracking` globally off, or add the `AsNoTracking()` extension method to further reduce the CPU load of you do not need change tracking.

Comment: I have to load all ClientSecrets and Scopes related to the client with given id, because I need it for further business logic. Besides, how can I load the client and then load the Scopes?